# Formatting Dates in Freemarker Where Date Type is Unknown

Tags: freemarker

I have a Freemarker function whose aim is to print any value passed to it and am having difficulty handling dates in particular.

I understand that when Freemarker cannot determine what portion of a date is in use, that it will error when attempting to print the value directly, and so some special-casing is required for dates, but I've been unable to find a reliable workaround of this feature.

My function looks something like this:

```
<#function format value=''>
    <#if value?is_date>
        <#-- code to attempt to handle all types of date -->
    <#else>
        <#-- handle non-date values -->
    </#if>
</#function>
```

So far, I have tried the following:

First attempt: just always print date and time; e.g. `value?datetime`

Problem: bombs if the value has already 'been told' it's date-only (e.g. `format(value?date)` - a usage I want to support)

Second attempt: attempt to print raw value using attempt/recover directives to handle problem cases; e.g.

```
<#attempt>
    <#return value>
<#recover>
    <#return value?datetime>
</#attempt>
```

Problem: the attempt/recover directives don't successful catch the exception - instead it's propagated out as before

I've tried many other things but the above approaches were the more sensible, and unfortunately neither were successful. There seems to be a catch-22: if the date-type is unknown I can only print by choosing an arbitrary type to apply to all date values, but if I attempt to apply that type to a known-type date, it will fail where the types don't match.

Is there any way to determine whether the date type of a value is known before trying to print the value? If so, I could use the ?datetime built in only when necessary.

Ideally, I could tell Freemarker to just print the full date where it's unable to determine the exact type, instead of bombing - but I'm not sure this is currently possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: In FreeMarker 2.3.21 you can use `<#if value?is_date_like>${value?datetime_if_unknown}<#else>...`

Yeah, there should exist something like `?is_unknown_type_date`, but it doesn't... I'm an FM maintainer so I will add that in 2.3.21 (but don't hold your breath until that's released). Meanwhile, you can write a `TemplateMethodModelEx` that does just that. Implementing it trivial as you will see, how to make them accessible to templates is a bit underdocumented... One way is just doping the `TemplateMethodModelEx` into the data-model or into the "shared variable" set of the `Configuration`. Another is putting this into some of your commonly `#import`-ed or `#included` template like `<#assign isUnknownTypeDate='com.example.IsUnknownTypeDateMethod'?new()>`.

BTW, `#recover` works for me for this (using a nightly 2.3.21, but I don't remember that it was ever broken). But don't use it for this anyway, as it will log the error. `#recover` is for emergency situations only, not for normal program flow.

As of providing a default format for unknowns-type dates... I feel uneasy about it as then these issues won't be caught during development, and very few will care to use a different FM configuration for production than for development.

Comment: Yes, the logging of the recover put me off that too. I kind of guessed the reason why you might not want to provide the default format for dates; it's the same philosophy behind the null stuff I suppose, and I appreciate where you're coming from there. Haven't had much experience on the API side yet, but will try your suggestion next week. Thanks again - really enjoying Freemarker in general.